# I changed name of css containing folder now html page is not refering css files

Tags: css

I changed html code also by changing new directries of css files. How can I solve this matter. I want to add different html files with different css files in the same wamp server. That's why I changed css file folder name.

I want to know how to change css files and images containing folder names without affecting html file view.

Comment: This is a bit unclear, could you please be more specific?

Comment: There are two html files.but css files are having diferent names.but more similar to each other.when i put those two in to localhost html files are not displaying some of css codes.so i changes css files dir names and also html code by adding new dir s.but still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's relative to the stylesheet, but I recommend you to make the URLs relative to your URL:

```
div#header { 
  background-image: URL(/images/header-background.jpg);
}
```

you can move your files around without needing to refactor them in the future.

Comment: Yes, I agree to this. I will do this and state the results.